# SharePoint WCF service to upload doc

Tags: wcf, sharepoint

Is it possible to create a WCF client to upload file (doc) to Sharepoint? 
  My problem, I can upload file to SharePoint use list asmx web service, but it conflict with Oracle.DataAccess.dll on Windows 7 64 bit. So I am thinking if there is any way to do it without web reference.

Thank you
Wes

Comment: what kind of conflict to you have with oracle ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading document can be achieved using a simple http PUT request